# stop subdomain access root

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdomain

i have root and subdomain (for my friend) like this

/home/blahblah/
/home/blahblah/domain.com/

(Apache server)

can i stop subdomain access root by using some php shell script?

Comment: You need to be a lot clearer about what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Can you elaborate on the question?

You can use .htaccess files to restrict/provide access to various things. You can look at the following site for more information:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html

(depending on your Apache version)

If you're referring to preventing access to other directories when using ftp / sftp, you can set up an account to login into a chroot environment with no access to other areas.